# How can I get the whole info for a transaction whose outputs are spent?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, json-rpc, txindex

I use the RPC method `getrawtransaction` to get the whole info for a transaction. But if I understood right, it works only for transactions which contain at least one unspent output.

How can I get the whole info as provided by `getrawtransaction` for a transaction whose outputs are all spent. Or how does Blockcypher implement this?

For example this tx:
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/501553f8a27cfb8f661e9c977b923908642c1817ef6037eb104da8dfb892890a/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, what you’re looking for is a “txindex=1” in your ‘bitcoin.conf’. It allows you to run ‘getrawtransaction’ to recall transactions that don’t spend from your wallet/don’t pay to your wallet/are not in the mempool. Furthermore, it’s named “Index transactions by TXID”.

Comment: That's incorrect, getrawtransaction doesn't require transactions to have unspent outputs, if txindex=1 is enabled. For example, http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getrawtransaction/5119419d1bd6af11277d81443852f6e2ffb3bcaddf303335e60aa199ad7a5d36/0 works, although the transaction has no unspent outputs.

Comment: Yes, sorry It was my mistake, I forgot reboot bitcoin core after change bitcoin.conf file to "txindex=1" and thought that I use new configuration. Thank you for your help!